# Storing range of numbers in a String[] or an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

i want to store a range of numbers into an array or a string[]. the range in 1 - 100. Please help. here is the code i tried:

```
static Array SetNum()
        {
        var initial = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(initial.ToString());
        return initial;
}
```

When i tried to run the program. I got System.int32[] on the output.

Comment: initial has all the values. Iterate through it to print

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It worked!!!

Comment: Please don't return `Array` from anything - it's so 10 years ago. There are better approaches.

Comment: What would be a better approach? I am new to programming :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're trying to do. You description of your problem doesn't gel with the code. But my best guess, based on your code is this:

```
static int[] SetNum()
{
    var initial = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", initial));
    return initial;
}
```